# Previewing updates to published content

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to preview changes made to published content before the content goes live? Or do you always have to unpublish content before editing and then save and preview before publishing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Preview your content before Publish the changes to go live and you do not need to unpublish it to see the preview.
Do the follwoing steps:

1. Navigate to Admin > Structure > Content Type and click Edit in front of your content type.
2. In the submission form settings tab.
3. Locate Preview before submitting and check Required.
4. Save the content type.
5. Navigate to Admin > Add Content > [Your Content Type].
6. You can see the Preview button listed next to Save node button.

Comment: Thanks v much Shrikant, very straightforward and I've implemented that not the relevant content. I'm only getting a trimmed view in preview that doesn't show me the actual page layout with images, page banners and text formatting. Is there another step I need to take to see the full page layout?

Comment: Hey Michelle, You can try https://www.drupal.org/project/pagepreview module to see the preview page with layout and design.